# The tags "numerical-methods" and "numerical-analysis"

Tags: discussion, tagging

While trying to search for numerical analysis related questions, I discovered the existence of two tags [numerical-methods](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/numerical-methods) and [numerical-analysis](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/numerical-analysis). Although there were very few questions with the tag "numerical-analysis", the presence of the two seems redundant to me. Also, a "numerical-analysis" tag seems to be more appropriate. Should the tags be merged and "numerical-methods" be replaced by "numerical-analysis"?

Comment: @ArthurFischer It seem that the link http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/numerical-analysis goes directly to the "numerical-methods" tagged question. Are the tags already merged?

Comment: Yes.  It seems that numerical-methods has beaten out numerical-analysis as the tag of choice.

Comment: I think self-deleting questions is generally frowned upon.  Just accept an answer (... oops, you already have ...) and the issue will be considered resolved.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are correct that there is a redundancy; these two tags have already been merged as they are synonyms of each other.  Clicking on the tag links in the OP will bring you to the same spot.

But it seems as though "numerical-methods" beat out "numerical-analysis" as the tag of choice.

Note that there is a list of all tag synonyms [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/tags/synonyms?filter=all&tab=master).